# Identify City Skyline

Tags: usa, identify-this

This is a photo of a skyline from 1997. We drove from Dallas to Niagara Falls and went through Arkansas, Tennessee, Kentucky, Ohio, Pennsylvania and New York. Google can't recognize it. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Are there photos before and/or after this one (on the device or storage, if digital; on the negatives, if analog) that you have identified? That would help narrow down the search.

Comment: If you took the photo with an iPhone or Android, the latitude and longitude are encoded inside the file.

Comment: @WGroleau this was taken in 1997. iPhones and Android did not exist. EXIF (the means of encoding file metadata within the image file) did not exist.

Comment: Actually, to correct myself, the initial version of EXIF had recently been defined. Still, even if the photographer had a very up to date digital camera at that time, it would likely only have captured date and time and possibly the camera settings - not the location. In those days cameras did not have GPS receivers built into them....

Comment: And as GPS receivers use batteries, not everybody likes having them on.

Comment: gps already existed but it was pretty much useless for civilians before 2000 because of the intentional accuracy degradation (military business) so nobody would produce a camera with the GPS receiver back then

Comment: I love how this comments section has just diverged into nitpicking if/how this camera would have had gps access.

Comment: @szulat nonsense, even with intentional degradation you were only off by a small amount. The reason was cost and demand and has nothing to do with that.

Comment: I keep clicking this because I think it's about the indie game Cities: Skylines.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This appears to be Buffalo NY, below is a screenshot from Google Maps streetview from the I-190 looking north, approximately [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/I-190,+New+York,+USA/@42.8764218,-78.9013761,13z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x89d36c0fccb9d453:0xa95cc3303435ae77!8m2!3d42.8764329!4d-78.8674799?hl=en) (link to Google Maps).

[image: Buffalo NY]

Comment: nice!  Did you recognize the city/view and poke around for a matching street view photo, or did you use some other strategy to identify the city?

Comment: I did a Google Image search which didn't find a match, but under "Visually Similar Images" one of the first images was of Buffalo - it seemed to have potential so I looked at a few more photos of the Buffalo skyline, and the Liberty building that was the giveaway (the building in the middle with the two pyramid shapes on the roof).

Comment: @ascha Like magic ...!

Comment: Thanks so much - Buffalo it is! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Pretty close, but I think you want to back up about a half a mile (east) to match the angle better.  I also think the original photo was taken from slightly lower than the Google streetview - likely from inside a moving car rather than with the roof-mounted camera they use.  Camera focal length would also make a big difference, hard to match it exactly if you don't know what type of lenses were used in both cases.

Comment: @TammyTerryRodriguez, if you are happy with the answer, please accept the answer. That is the green tick to the side of the answer.

Comment: @BenBolker FWIW, I thought the tall brown building on the right was [Buffalo City Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_City_Hall), so I got it on a fluke :p It's actually the [Rand Building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_Building).

Answer (score 5):

This is the exact place where you took that pic: https://goo.gl/maps/yn1QU65jutoSf7vr9
[image]